# How to improve the performance of CodeContract rewriter in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-contracts

We've got a medium sized VisualStudio solution containing 60 projects. Every project contains code contracts. Since we use `Contract.Requires<T>` for our preconditions we need to have our assemblies rewritten after compilation.

Assembly mode is 'Standard Contract Requires', Runtime checking is set to 'full' and we have 'Assert on contract failure' set. Contract reference assembly is set to 'Build'.

After changing from VS2010 to VS2012 (VS2010 was uninstalled before installation) our solution would build in **1m 30s**. After installing the CodeContracts installation package the build time increased to **5m 30s** (as the binary rewriter was now rewriting the assemblies).

This is a lot longer than it took to build the solution in VS2010, which took about 3m to for a full rebuild.

Has anyone experienced a similar slowdown or has an idea how the situation can be improved?

We've already tried to disable building of the contract reference assembly but this didn't change anything.

Comment: One of my colleagues is using VS2012 with our solution that has code contracts, and he's not seeing this (although we only have about 5 projects). I wonder though if its related to this [forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/d5a61334-9404-4a43-9836-294e71196c62).

Answer (score 0):

We have a solution with over 90 projects running the rewriter on most of them. On a HP z420, with parallel build on, I can build the solution in about 1 min 40 seconds. The rewriter does add 2-10 seconds per project depending on the size of the dll being rewritten. This is with the latest 1.5.60409.11 release.

Comment: One suggestion I posted on the CodeContract forum is to set the 32bit req bit on the executable to run the CLR in 32bit mode. On a 64bit machine, this can shave off a few seconds. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/ff115adb-d2ed-4aaf-8889-3b8732517fdb

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a serious slowdown with the static checker, not sure if that applies here though. I'm not positive but I think they recently changed how caching works. I think it used a file based cache by default but no longer has that option. In the CC settings for your project there is a option to specify a SQL instance to use for caching. It took me a while to get it right but I use the SQL Express instance on my machine. I have "Cache Results" checked and "SQL Server" set to `.\SQLEXPRESS`. When the tools run you should see messages about caching in the output window when it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

When I start a new solution the first thing I do is to create a new solution configuration:

1. Debug
2. Debug CC
3. Release

I then only enable Code Contracts on Debug CC. This allows me to compile fast in debug mode and switch to a Code Contracts build when I am close to a commit.